# Why $\int_{\mathbb R^d} u^p=\int_0^\infty \mu(t)d(t^p)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $u$ a non negative lipschitz continuous function that decay fast at infinity. Let $$\mu(t)=m\{x\in \mathbb R^d\mid u(x)>t\}.$$
Why $$\int_{\mathbb R^d}u^p=\int_0^\infty \mu(t)\mathrm d(t^p)\ \ ?$$

**Attempts**

If $p=1$, then $$\int_0^\infty \mu(t)dt=\int_0^\infty \int_{\{x\mid u(x)>t\}}dxdt=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\left(\int_0^{u(x)}dt\right)dx=\int_{\mathbb R^d}u(x)dx.$$

But in the case where $p>1$, I don't know how to do. In fact, I don't understand the notation $\mathrm d(t^p)$.